# How to use mvc:resources tag

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am using Spring Security 3. I have files unders /js, /css and /img folders and imports them HTML files. I want to serve them with mvc:resource because I can add expire-head easily and I think it gives a url-rewriting ability. However I am so new to Spring Security and don't know the purpose of it and how can I use it?

An example usage at my HTML webpages:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/main.css"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `mvc:resources` tag has nothing to do with Spring Security - it tells Spring MVC to not pass those resources through the `RequestDispatcher` servlet, but to serve them up directly.  Instead, you want to exclude those same directories from Spring Security resource controls, as follows:

```
<intercept-url pattern="/css/**" filters="none"/>
<intercept-url pattern="/js/**" filters="none"/>
<intercept-url pattern="/img/**" filters="none"/>
```

See http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/ns-config.html#ns-minimal for full details.

Comment: I wantrd to use it's cache-period="31556926" property but I think I should do it manually. Also I have HTML files instead of JSP files and does it means that I can't use them?

Comment: It writes that tag do something for Last-Modified header and cache-period time. How can I do them without spring?

Comment: I"m now a little confused.  What exactly are you trying to accomplish, and how does Spring Security play into it?  From your comments, it doesn't sound like security is an issue here at all.